# Hibernate: Incrementar a partir de um valor específico

Tags: java, hibernate

Criei um atributo do tipo `Integer` chamado matrícula e quero que, quando o usuário for se cadastrar, o valor dessa matrícula seja gerado automaticamente e salvo no mysql a partir de um certo valor(Ex: 95000) e conforme outros vão se cadastrando, será a última matrícula usada + 1 (95001, 95002...).

Tem como fazer isso com o Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi direito mas vamos lá. Vou assumir que você já possui um banco MySQL rodando e que precisará recuperar a última (maior) matrícula utilizada e utilizá-la para determinar qual o número da matrícula do novo cadastro que está criando.

Primeiro de tudo, utilize uma query para poder recuperar os valores das matrículas e compará-las entre si para descobrir qual é a maior.

```
private int getUltimaMatricula() {
  EntityManager em = createEntityManagerFactory();
  em.getTransaction().begin();
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT t.coluna1 from tabela t where t.campo1 = :campo1");

    // campo1 e o que voce ira utilizar para recuperar as matriculas, utilizando jpql 
    // neste caso.
    q.setParameter("campo1", campo1);

    List<Integer> result = q.getResultList();

  int maiorNumero = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

  for(i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
    if (result.get(i) > maiorNumero)
      maiorNumero = result.get(i);
  }

  em.getTransaction().commit();
  em.close();

  return maiorValor;
}
```

Depois isso, chame este método dentro do seu método "persist" ou algo do tipo e utilize o número retornado +1 para determinar o número da nova matrícula.

Qualquer dúvida, comente aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui!
Segui a sua ideia e fiz assim:

```
private void gerarMatricula(Aluno a) {

    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    query = session.createQuery("select matricula from Aluno");

    List<Integer> result = query.list();
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        a.setMatricula(45100); //O primeiro aluno cadastrado receberá a matricula 45100, 

    } else{
        int maiorNumero = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            if (result.get(i) > maiorNumero)
                maiorNumero = result.get(i);

        }
        a.setMatricula(maiorNumero + 1);
    }


}
```

Depois chamei esse método no meu "persist":

```
public void create(Aluno a) throws Exception {

    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    gerarMatricula(a);
    CriptografarSenha cs = new CriptografarSenha();
    cs.criptografia(a); //Criptografar a senha
    session.save(a);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();

}
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Você quis dizer `Obrigado pela ajuda!` ou `De nada pela ajuda!` ? rs.. Pois aparentemente você resolveu o problema do autor da pergunta, ou estou enganado?

Comment: Foi "Obrigado pela ajuda" mesmo, rsrs, porque eu sou o autor da pergunta, mas quando eu perguntei, ainda não estava cadastrado. Perguntei como convidado, por isso o nome está diferente. Postei a solução para ajudar caso alguém precise.

Comment: Você pode mesclar suas contas entrando em contato pela página: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact assim você poderá reaver a autoria da pergunta e aceitar a resposta que mais lhe ajudou, caso considere-a assim.